# Adding multiple rasters produces unexpected results. I have set the data extent to the same in all rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, extents

I am trying to add three rasters together. I'm trying to figure out where I am going wrong so I am going to list out what I am doing:

- I have Raster_1, Raster_2 and Raster_3.
- Raster_1 and Raster_2 were set to the extent of Raster_3
- I used the Map Algebra tool to write "Raster_1 + Raster_2 + Raster_3" = Raster_4
- Raster_4 only has areas where all three previous rasters intersect.
- I thought that by setting the extent of Raster_1 and Raster_2 to Raster_3 this wouldn't be an issue.
- I went to check that I had done this correctly but the extents had gone back to their previous extents.
- I reset Raster_1 and Raster_2 to the extent of Raster_3 but they are not the same. I have no idea why they would not be the same if that's how I am setting them. The setting I am using is:

> the rectangular extent of Raster_3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In raster calculations if at least one of your data has no data values, the result will be given a no data, therefore calculation happens only for those cells you have data value in all three rasters. So setting the same extent is not enough.

1. use the `Con((IsNULL(Raster_x),0,RAster_x)` raster calculation on all your three rasters in order to change the no data values into a distinct number, I arbitrarily used `0`, as you said your next step is to sum the rasters, therefore a cell that is zero won't affect your operation, if you were to multiply the rasters though, `1` would be a better choice.  Make sure you set the extent to the largest raster.
2. Do your raster sum operation

Comment: One thing to be careful is , you won't be able to tell between the 'zeroes' from your original data and the ones from the new raster operation at step 1 in my answer. The other option is to set a large signed integer for the no data cells at step 1, for example `-999999` (This works if all your data is >=0) and to later select all  negative cells from the resulting raster after step 2 and add `+999999` to them.

Comment: All of my data is 0.1 to 1. For me to even be evaluating this data, it needs to be at least 0.1. Does this still matter? I'm doing a test run of the above now.

Comment: in that case, setting zero to all your no data will be fine, you'd know any zero in the three rasters means no data after doing step 1. It shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I just realized my cell size is different. Should I be setting the cell size to both the higher or the lower cell? This is a difference of 0.59 to 0.00048. For right now, the accuracy of this doesn't matter but ArcGIS has been executing making Raster_2 which is normally 5.99 to 0.00048 in order to match Raster_1 which naturally has 0.000048 for quite awhile now.

Comment: oh okay,  I'd suggest re-sampling all your 5.99 rasters to the 0.00048. so that all of your three rasters have the same cells size. If resampling, do it before doing the conditional analysis at step 1.

Comment: I decided to merge the polygons in question with a rectangle around the project area. This produced polygons I wanted. However, when I went to convert to rasters (both had cell sizes of 6.3 which is good), the outputs were a single area (my areas now previously looked like sneezes on a square) with only one value.

It seems to me I traded one problem for another. Any thoughts? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: I am a bit confused now, are the polygons your source data from which you got your 3  rasters in the original post? You do not have to start from scratch i mean from converting from the polygons. [1]. Make the cell size of all the 3 rasters the same by going to Arctoolbox > Raster > Raster Processing > Resample and convert 2 of the rasters to match the 3rd in ArcGIS (use the rasters that you converted with the default cell setting, the sneezes in a square:) ). [2]. use the raster calculator and do the Con function as given above, [3]. do your sum.

Comment: I am using the resampling tool now and it gives me error message 000995 saying that the resampled cell size is too great or too small for either raster that I try to resample.

Comment: are the raster files too large to upload somewhere and send a link? can you post a screen shot of how you parametrized the resample function?... Oh wait, when you do resample, make sure you go to the environmental settings and specify, processing extent (use the extent of the raster you are resampling for now), cell size, coordinate system etc..

Comment: Yes, I will upload screen shots but it will be later on tonight when I have access to imgur.

Comment: This problem ended up being solved using a tool that counts the overlapping polygons, no conversion to raster required. Just thought I would let you know! Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!